# Multiple rows are getting inserted into a table (which is not desired) as part of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

Update:  This still remain a mystery. Checked the calling code and we did not find anything that would make the SP run in a loop. 
For now we have split the SP into two which seems to have arrested the issue although not able to reason how that has helped out.

Database: MS SQL Server.

I have a SP which performs few operations - i.e inserts a row into 3 tables based on certain status as part of that SP being called.

It is getting called from our web application based on a user action.

We have cases, few times a day where the same row gets inserted multiple times (sometime more than 50+) with the same values in each row except that if you look at the datetime when the row was inserted there is a difference of few milliseconds.  So it is unlikely that the user is initiating that action.

This SP is not running in a Transaction or with any locks however it is getting called probably concurrently multiple times as we have many concurrent users on the web application invoking this action.

My question is what is causing the same row to insert so many times?  If concurrent execution of SP was an issue where we are updating same row then it is understood one may overwrite the other.  However in this case each user calls in the SP with different parameters.

I have put the said operation in a Transaction to monitor the behavior however was looking to find out what exactly causes these kind of multiple inserts with same value just a few milliseconds apart?

```
  USE [ABC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyWithLog] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyWithLog] 
(
--Insert using bulk
@stdfrm_id int,
@course_id int,
@stdfrm_scrt_apprvby int,
@stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment varchar(max),
@sRemainingDocs varchar(max),
@DTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny AS dbo.MyDTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN   

DECLARE @result char
SET @result='N'

--New
declare @AuditCount int=0;
select @AuditCount=count(scrtaudit_id) from tbl_ProcessAdmittedScrutinyAuditLog 
where stdfrm_id=@stdfrm_id and stdfrm_scrt_apprvby=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvby 
and stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment and convert(date,stdfrm_scrt_apprvon,103)=convert(date,getdate(),103)
 --Checked extra conditon to avoid repeatation
 if(@AuditCount=0)
 BEGIN
 --Call Insert


BEGIN TRY


/*Remaining Documents----------*/
    DECLARE @sdtdoc_id Table (n int primary key identity(1,1), id int) 
    if(@sRemainingDocs is not null)
    begin
    --INSERT INTO @sdtdoc_id (id)   SELECT Name from splitstring(@sRemainingDocs)
    INSERT INTO @sdtdoc_id (id) SELECT [Value] from dbo.FN_ListToTable(@sRemainingDocs,',')
    end
    Declare @isRemaining int=0;
    SELECT @isRemaining=Count(*) FROM @sdtdoc_id

/*Calculate stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus*/
Declare @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus char(1)='A';--Approved
Declare @TotalDescripancies int;
select @TotalDescripancies=count(doc_id) from @DTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny where doc_id_scrtyn='Y'
if(@isRemaining>0)
begin
    set @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus='H';--Discrepancies Found
end
else if exists (select count(doc_id) from @DTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny where doc_id_scrtyn='Y')
begin
    if(@TotalDescripancies>0)
    begin
        set @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus='H';--Discrepancies Found
    end     
end
/* Check if Discrepancies Found first time then assign to Checker o.w assign to direct college  like grievance*/
if(@stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus='H')
begin
declare @countAuditLog int=0;
select @countAuditLog=count(stdfrm_id) from tbl_ProcessAdmittedScrutinyAuditLog where stdfrm_id =@stdfrm_id
if (@countAuditLog=0)
begin
 set @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus='G'--'E';--Discrepancies Found set Edit request assign to Checker 
end
--else if (@countAuditLog=1)
-- begin
--set @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus='G';--Discrepancies Found set Grievance assign to college
-- end
end
/*----------------------*/

/*Update status in original table-----*/
Update tbl_ProcessAdmitted set stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus
,stdfrm_scrt_apprvon=getdate(),stdfrm_scrt_apprvby=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvby
,stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment
where stdfrm_id =@stdfrm_id

/*Add in Main Student Log-----------*/
/********* The row here gets inserted multiple times *******************/
INSERT into tbl_ProcessAdmittedScrutinyAuditLog
(stdfrm_id, stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus, stdfrm_scrt_apprvon, stdfrm_scrt_apprvby, stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment )
values
(@stdfrm_id, @stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus, getdate(), @stdfrm_scrt_apprvby, @stdfrm_scrt_apprvcomment)

DECLARE @scrtaudit_id int =@@identity
/*Completed -------------------------*/

DELETE FROM tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny WHERE stdfrm_id =@stdfrm_id
SET NOCOUNT ON;

/********* The row here gets inserted multiple times *******************/
INSERT tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny
(stdfrm_id, course_id, doc_id, doc_id_scrtyn, doc_id_scrtrmrk, doc_id_comment) 
SELECT @stdfrm_id, @course_id, doc_id, doc_id_scrtyn, doc_id_scrtrmrk, doc_id_comment
FROM @DTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny;

/*Scrutiny Document Log -------------------------*/

/********* The row here gets inserted multiple times *******************/
INSERT tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyAuditLog
(scrtaudit_id,stdfrm_id, course_id, doc_id, doc_id_scrtyn, doc_id_scrtrmrk, doc_id_comment) 
SELECT @scrtaudit_id,@stdfrm_id, @course_id, doc_id, doc_id_scrtyn, doc_id_scrtrmrk, doc_id_comment
FROM @DTProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutiny;

/*Remaining Documents Insert into table*/

DELETE FROM tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyRemiaing WHERE stdfrm_id =@stdfrm_id

        DECLARE @Id int,@doc_id int
        WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM @sdtdoc_id) > 0
            BEGIN
                Select Top 1 @Id = n,@doc_id=id From @sdtdoc_id                 
                --Do some processing here

                insert into tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyRemiaing(stdfrm_id, doc_id ) 
                values (@stdfrm_id,@doc_id)

                insert into tbl_ProcessAdmittedDocUploadScrutinyRemiaingAuditLog
                (scrtaudit_id, stdfrm_id, doc_id ) 
                values (@scrtaudit_id,@stdfrm_id,@doc_id)

                DELETE FROM @sdtdoc_id WHERE n = @Id

            END --Begin end While
/*End Remaining Documents-----------*/

SET @result=@stdfrm_scrt_apprvstatus    

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @result='N'


insert into tbl_ErrorSql( ErrorMessage,  stdfrm_id)
values(coalesce(Error_Message(),ERROR_LINE()),@stdfrm_id)
END CATCH;

--End of Call Insert
END

SELECT @result

END
```

Comment: Could you provide the sp structure please.

Comment: Could you pls share what code you have tried?

Comment: Actually, before starting to investigate I advice you to check how many times that SP executed for same parameters. You can check it with "SQL Server Profiler". If it executed multiple times that's mean you need to investigate the software code instead of SP code first.

Comment: @Rahul  were you able to bring web application user id into SP?

Comment: Poorly formatted code is not likely to attract much interest and only increases the effort to understand it. I see you put a comment in about the multiple inserts. As the statement that follows it is a simple <insert . values> statement, it can only insert a single row. Therefore, the logical assumption is that the calling code is the problem.

Comment: Zeki - have not looked at it. will check.  Santhana - I believe I do have access to the web application user id.  Although based on the row it is inserting I know which application user id it is tied to and so far it seems its not specific to any particular one.  This is a random occurrence.  SMor yes, will investigate the calling code through Profiler as suggested above.  It seems from all the comments that nothing specific about the SP that would do this and the problem is external to it.